# How to access `object` data better than `$collection[0]->object`

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am new to PDO PHP and I'm confident that I'm not writing it in an efficient manner. I'm constantly struggling with how to get `object` data from within a `collection` and the way I'm doing it is ugly.

For example, I have two tables `work_orders` and `aircraft`. I want to get the aircraft registration from the `aircraft` table, through the use of my `aircraft_id` field located in my `work_orders` table.

Here is what I have in my Controller:

```
// Temporary injection
$order_number = '502';

// Get the aircraft_id that corresponds to the work order supplied
$aircraft_id = $workorder->select('aircraft_id')
                            ->where('id', $order_number)
                            ->get();

// Assigned the aircraft_id to a variable
$aircraft_id = $aircraft_id[0]->aircraft_id;

// Use the aircraft_id to find get the aircraft data
$aircraft = $aircraft->findOrFail($aircraft_id);
```

I realize that this has `join()` written all over it, and I did have it joined, but I got here by trying to solve my problem...if that makes sense.

The part that's getting me all the time is I *want* to simply type `$aircraft_id->aircraft_id` and I end up hitting the same wall.

Is there a better way to structure my query, or is this just the way it is?

**EDIT**

My `WorkOrder` Model:

```
public function aircraft()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Aircraft::class);
}
```

Comment: RE: the annoyance with having to indicate the index for the row, you could just use the `first()` function instead of `get()` if I am not mistaken?

Comment: I just replaced `get()` with `first()` and that does get rid of the need for `[0]` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of whole code you can use:

```
// Temporary injection
$order_number = '502';

// Use the aircraft_id to find get the aircraft data
$aircraft = $aircraft->findOrFail($workorder->select('aircraft_id')->findOrFail($order_number)->aircraft_id);
```

Instead of:

```
->where('id', $order_number)->get();
```

you can use here

`->find($order_number)` (or better `->findOrFail($order_number)` to make sure record exists and you won't take any action on `null`) - it will take only the first record with given id.

Now you simply access property `aircraft_id` and that's it